# проблема с сессиями, питон

Tags: python, парсер, requests, сессия

почему у меня аутентификация работает, а запрос на удаление пользователя из списка - возвращает ошибку 302? по запросам всё совпадает с тем, что происходит в браузере

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests

import urllib.parse
import re

session = requests.session()

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko'}

# зайти в fiddler открыть ie залогиниться, в логе найти запрос /login/ и из его headers скопировать поле начинающееся с __cfduid, вставить данные ниже ( ---login pu2ok54y.iap@20minutemail.it   ---- pass pu2ok54y.iap@20minutemail.it)
cookies = {
    'Cookie': ' __cfduid=d6626e92c9f16e68333e7659b784b620e1529816191; beget=begetok; _ga=GA1.2.1295839351.1529816195; _gid=GA1.2.931604904.1529816195; _ym_uid=1529816197676409622; _ym_d=1529816197; _ym_wasSynced=%7B%22time%22%3A1529816199338%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22webvisor%22%3A%7B%22date%22%3A%222011-10-31%2016%3A20%3A50%22%7D%2C%22eu%22%3A0%7D%2C%22bkParams%22%3A%7B%7D%7D; _ym_isad=2; _ym_visorc_27298664=w; PHPSESSID=04750aa9d58beacdfb2d6724833d9302; YII_CSRF_TOKEN=d53067916951e4214c1d0ad90028a810b41dc0f3s%3A88%3A%22azNHZjNaSmdpVDVCT283ZDFpQkdWdWFvYkxKRUZHdUmn94zfFrKlEa1j0OOl1Q8QDP-b9Sca0MtkOOU_05NSRQ%3D%3D%22%3B; caltat=a73f646177294c678a418cf2d60adb18'
}

uuu = (urllib.parse.unquote(cookies['Cookie']))
re2 = re.compile(r'(?:YII_CSRF_TOKEN=)(.*)(?:")', re.IGNORECASE)
YII_CSRF_TOKEN = re2.findall(str(uuu))[0]
YII_CSRF_TOKEN = YII_CSRF_TOKEN.split(':"')[1]


def auth():
    global headers
    global cookies
    url = 'http://bosslike.ru/login/'
    print(session.post(url=url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies))


def get_id_and_userlist():
    global headers
    global cookies
    url = 'http://bosslike.ru/tasks/instagram/subscribe/'
    r = session.post(url=url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)

    re1 = re.compile('пользователя(.*?)</a></h2>', re.IGNORECASE)
    usernames = re1.findall(str(r.text))

    re2 = re.compile('<h2><a class="do-task" href="javascript:;" data-task-id="(\d*)"', re.IGNORECASE)
    ids = re2.findall(str(r.text))

    print(usernames)
    print(ids)


def delete():
    global YII_CSRF_TOKEN
    global headers
    global cookies
    url = 'http://bosslike.ru/tasks/delete/'
    params = {'id': 7209355, 'YII_CSRF_TOKEN': YII_CSRF_TOKEN}
    print((session.post(url=url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=params)).text)


auth()
delete()

'''<Response [200]>
[ ' face_artist', ' maxim_staroverov', ' ayratmusin', ' veyron177', ' vladyushko', ' 444vadik444', ' magick_women', ' crystal_affection', ' ayyamiss', ' sasha_vermova']
['7209355', '6715003', '6249257', '5660565', '7356791', '5736882', '7088579', '7342100', '7300175', '6819423']
'''
```

Comment: 302 это не ошибка, а редирект. Уверен, в браузере тоже 302, просто он автоматически редиректит и вы этого не успеваете замечать

Comment: запрос выполняется но изменений не происходит, все запросы как у браузера

Comment: Хм, сайт в случае ошибки отвечает редиректом вместо того, чтобы ответить ошибкой. Плохой сайт)